# add the code for a widget (widget.xhtml) once but use it twice in same webpage, possible ? How?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a widget in my application that I need to display at two places(once in main page body and once through dialog box). Currently its code has been added twice in the page. Now I was thinking, If there was a way I could just include it only once and show the same instance in the dialog box, as in the main page body.

Can you suggest a way for this?

---

### I'm Using:-

JSF 2.0 with Facelets
 
Primefaces 3.0 M3 Snapshot

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "widget"? Do you want to reuse a specific instance of a JSF component? Or a piece of Facelets code?

Comment: By Widget, I mean  peice of facelets code or a part of a webpage like say a sidebar which may be composed of multiple JSF components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF 2 has exactly the feature you want: it's called [composite components](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/). I bascially allows you to write a bunch of Facelet code into a file and use it just like any other JSF component, pass parameters to it, etc.

Comment: Thanks but composite components doesn't help maintain a single instance for both the places. Actually my use case is something similar to twitter's new tweet sharing wizard. In twitter, there is a tweet sharing widget that is added to the body of the homepage & another tweet sharing widget is shown in the dialog box (that open by pressing the button on nav bar). In my case, since the markup for this widget is too large I was thinking if there is a way by which I could maintain just a single instance and use at both the places

Comment: @Marcos: um yes, they do. You have the markup only once and can use it many times within a page.